# Convert extension and open it using an application

Tags: javascript, html

I got a a script wherein I want to convert the extension to another one then open it using a specific application.

For instance, I got .mht file located in my Desktop. An html file with internal javascript on it.

What I want to happen is when I open the HTML file on internet explorer and click on the hyperlink, it should convert .mht file into .docx and open it using Microsoft Word. Unfortunately, my below code does not work, if i click the hyperlink, it does opens up Microsoft Word but giving me an error message saying that the file cannot be found. Can someone assist me with this please? Thanks in advance, will much appreciated.

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>

<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--

     function openDocument(file)
     {
        try
        {
            var Word = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application")
            var file;
            file = file.split(".");
            file = file[0]+".docx";
            Word.Visible = true
            Word.Documents.Open(file)
        }

        catch(exception)
        {
            if(Word)
            {
                alert(exception.message)
                Word.Quit()
            }
            window.location.href = file
        }
     }

     // -->
     </script>
   <TITLE>Launch Word - Local</Title>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>

<a href="javascript:openDocument('C:\Users\test\Desktop\KB.mht')">Summary</a>

   </BODY>
   </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

For security purpose, Javascript can't write on the filesystem, so it is impossible to change the extension of a file.

You should be able to do something with the new FileSystem API (check that tutorial : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), but it is available only on Chrome (http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem)

EDIT:
With an ActiveX, using GetFile may work:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = fso.GetFile("c:\\myfile.mht");   
file.name = "newName.newExt";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to run in Internet Explorer, is there any way?

Comment: In native Javascript, no.

With an ActiveX, you may use GetFile and then file.name = 'newname.ext'; but I never tried it.